# I don't understand the ordering of the file array returned by listFiles()

Tags: android

So, I've got a ListView that displays the names of all of the files in a certain directory.  This application also deletes files and adds new files to the directory.

I'd like the files to be displayed in the order of their creation, but this isn't always true with File(*directory*).listFiles().  If I start with an empty directory and start adding files, then the newest file goes in position 0 of the array, and ascends in order to the oldest.  However, if I delete any files and then add new ones, things get strange.  Here's an example...

Imagine that I've started with an empty directory, and added four files to it.  The array returned by listFiles() will be:

Position 0 = File #4 (fourth to be added)
P 1 = File #3
P 2 = File #2
P 3 = File #1

Then, I'll delete Files #2 and #3.  The array is:

P 0 = File #4
P 1 = File #1

So far, so good.  Now, I'll add two new files.  I'd expect the new array returned by listFiles() to be:

P 0 = File #6
P 1 = File #5
P 2 = File #4
P 3 = File #1

However, here's what it actually is:

P 0 = File #4
P 1 = File #6
P 2 = File #5
P 3 = File #1

But if I then add a File #7, the new array will be:

P 0 = File #7
P 1 = File #4
P 2 = File #6
P 3 = File #5
P 4 = File #1

Basically, if any files are deleted, then new files will fill their "old positions" in the array.  All of the "old positions" must be filled before any new files will go to Position 0.  Can anyone explain this behavior?  Also, is there a quick and easy way to re-sort the file array into my desired chronological order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the list of files is to use [File.listFiles()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) and the documentation states that this makes no guarantees about the order of the files returned.  Therefore you need to write a [Comparator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that uses [File.lastModified()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified()) and pass this, along with the array of files, to [Arrays.sort()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)).

**CODE:**

```
File[] files = directory.listFiles();

Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>(){
    public int compare(File f1, File f2)
    {
        return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
    } });
```

Try this and let me know what happen..

**EDIT:**

You might also look at [apache commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/), it has a built in [last modified comparator](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/comparator/LastModifiedFileComparator.html) and many other nice utilities for working with files.

Comment: @osweetman - You can accept this answer. If its solved your problem.. This is useful to you and other user also..

Comment: I was able to fix my issue with the following code:

    files = new File(directory).listFiles();
    Arrays.sort(files);

Because all of my files are named with their date/time of creation, it appears that I don't even need to use Comparator or File.lastModified().  Now that's quick and easy!